# Android application error "application has stopped unexpectedly" but it worked OK in the emulator.

Tags: android

I have created two application in android.Both the application runs fine in emulator. I have installed both applications in my phone. After installation one of my applications works ok, but the other application gives an error like "The application DemoTT(process com.tt) has stopped unexpectedly". What are the changes i have to do if I want to install it in my phone. I am doing thid for the first time so I don't have much idea. Please help me if you know the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many possibilities. 2 of which I can think of are

1. Some Permissions are not granted.
2. The project id com.tt is not unique.

Comment: may be both the applications you are referring to are having same id.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug the app with DDMS to trace the log so that you can clearly find root cause of issue.

This could be related to some service that you are using are not supported by device which you were testing.

~Abhijeet

Comment: Oh thanx for your suggestion but may i know how to debug the app from my phone??